# WPF: Binding to a (observable) Dictionary

Tags: wpf, binding, dictionary, indexing, observable

I'm using this ObservableCollection-Class within my Project: [Link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)
I want to Bind a RibbonMenuButton to a `ObservableDictionary<string,bool>`:

```
<r:RibbonMenuButton ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}">
    <r:RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonMenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </style>
    </r:RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</r:RibbonMenuButton>
```

But I get exceptions because the Value-Properties of the internal IDictionary-KeyValuePairs are readonly. Any Idea how to solve this?

I thought about something like:

```
<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Source=MyDictionary[{Binding Path=Key}]}"/>
```

But this won't work 'cause of {Binding} in {Binding}...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work, because your dictionary isn't treated as a dictionary but as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>`. So each `RibbonMenuItem` is bound to a `KeyValuePair<string, bool>` with readonly properties `Key` and `Value`.
You can do <del>two</del> one thing<del>s</del>:

<del>1. Use an `ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, bool>>` instead of the dictionary and bind `IsChecked` to `Item2`.</del>
  2. Create a little helper class that contains a `IsChecked` property and change your dictionary to contain that class as the value and bind `IsChecked` to `Value.IsChecked`.

I would go with answer two, because the needed changes and possible side effects are smaller.
My answer assumes that you want to have a two way binding on `IsChecked`. If not, go with the answer of slugster.

Comment: Tuple... That was the class I was searching for, works perfekt for me!

Comment: narf ... Touple.Item1/2 are readonly, too. So I'm going to use a helper-class, tought i could avoid this...

Comment: +1, once the OP elaborated and required two way binding then this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

WPF binding is two-way by default. Make it one-way and see if that solves your issue.

```
<r:RibbonMenuButton ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}">
    <r:RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonMenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </style>
    </r:RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</r:RibbonMenuButton>
```

Here is a reference for you: [MSDN Windows Presentation Foundation Data Binding: Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) (specifically check the section *Binding Mode* close to the bottom of the page)

Comment: Won't work... I want to reflect the IsChecked-State of the Checkbox to my ViewModel ;)

Answer (score 1):

If You want to bind `MenuItems` to `Dictionary<string, bool>` without using a helper class, like the accepted answer suggests, here is the *minimal-change* solution (no need to add anything else):

- define a `Click` event inside the `ItemContainerStyle` whose `ClickEventHandler` will update the dicitonary.
- declare a dictionary and initialize it inside the UserControl's / Window's constructor

In code:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<MenuItem Header="_My settings" ItemsSource="{Binding MySettings}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <!-- this is the main line of code -->
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MySettings_ItemClick"/>
      </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // properties...

    // Declaration of the dictionary
    public Dictionary<string, bool> MySettings{ get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Initialize the dictionary
        MySettings = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
        {
            { "SettingOne", true}
            // Other pairs..
        };
    }
    // other things..

    // ClickEvent hanlder
    private void MySettings_ItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem clickedItem = (sender as MenuItem);
        MySettings[clickedItem.Header as string] = clickedItem.IsChecked;
    }
} // end of MainWindow class
```

That's it! You're all set!

Credits to [slugster and his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030226/2101117) for XAML code for OneWay binding :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution to this problem of binding to dictionaries I created an UpdateableKeyValuePair and return that instaed of the usual KeyValuePair. Here is my class:

```
   public class UpdateableKeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>
      {
      private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _owner;
      private TKey _key;
      public UpdateableKeyValuePair(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Owner, TKey Key_)
         {
         _owner = Owner;
         _key = Key_;
         }

      public TKey Key
         {
         get
            {
            return _key;
            }
         }

      public TValue Value
        {
        get
          {
          return _owner[_key];
          }
       set
         {
          _owner[_key] = value;
         }
      }
    }
```